# Need help figuring equation of partial sums out

Tags: inequality, summation, proof-explanation, fourier-series

This might be an easy question, but I just can't figure out the steps in this equation in a proof.
[image]

$ S_n(g,t) $ is the n-th partial Sum : $ \sum_{-n}^n \hat{g} (j) e^{ijt} $
And also here you need to use that you can write $ \hat{f}(j)= \Omega_j \hat{g}(j) $

For me it woud be:
$$S_n(g,t)-S_m(g,t)= \sum_{-n}^n \hat{g}(j)e^{ijt}- \sum_{-m}^m \hat{g}(j)e^{ijt}$$ $$= \sum_{-n}^n \hat{g}(j)e^{ijt} \Omega_j \frac{1}{ \Omega_j}- \sum_{-m}^m \hat{g}(j)e^{ijt} \Omega_j \frac{1}{ \Omega_j}= \sum_{-n}^n \hat{f}(j)e^{ijt} \Omega^{-1}- \sum_{-m}^m \hat{f}(j)e^{ijt} \Omega^{-1}
$$

Also know about the cauchy criteria for sequences..but this just doesn't add up for me..
I appreciate any help!!

Comment: What is $\{-n.-n+1,...,0,1,2,...+n\} \setminus \{-m.-m+1,...,0,1,2,...+m\}$?

Comment: isn't it $ \{m+1,...,n \} $?

Comment: What about $-n,-n+1,...-m-1$?

Comment: so one sum ist going $ \{-n,...,-m-1 \} $ and the other $ \{ m+1,...,n \}$

Comment: Yes, that exactly how the proof starts.

Comment: and why can you say that the inequality $ |S_n(f,t)-S_m(f,t) \leq 2 \sup_n | S_n(f,t) | \Omega_{m+1}^{-1} $ holds?